# How do I find the normalized mean of a Stream?

Tags: java

I am stuck on how to find the normalized mean of the stream. The stream contains numbers and I am trying to find the normalized mean. The equation is Normalized `mean = (avg of stream - min of stream)/(max of stream - min of stream)`

`normalizedStream(Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5))` will give me 0.5

```
public static double normalizedMean(Stream<Integer> stream) {
    Integer max = max(stream);
    Integer min = min(stream);
    Integer sum = sum(stream);
    long count = count(stream);
    return (double) ((sum / count) - min) / (max - min);
}
```

When I do this they say the stream has already been piped.

Comment: Because it has. You need to get the current maximum, minimum and running sum using your own aggregator.

Comment: A stream is not a collection.  It's a stream of elements.  It has a source and an output.  When the output requests the next element, the stream passes one element down the chain from source to output.  It doesn't store every single element that ever passes through the stream.  If you want to know what the previous elements were, you have to have stored them yourself.

Comment: A stream which is once used cannot be used again. So, the same stream cannot be used to find the min, max, sun and count. Only one of those operation will work on a stream.

Comment: @dhruvtailor. Of course it can. You just have to do it yourself.

Comment: No. The same stream instance can't be used again. The stream is used when max element is calculated. After that the stream cannot be used. You have to create a new stream instance. @Mad Physicist

Comment: I probably cant do it all in one line right? I probably need the help of a helper function ?

Comment: well this is the equation i was given

Comment: `(double) ((sum / count) - min) / (max - min)` does all the calculations as integers and then converts to `double`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't consume a single stream more than once, so you have to either create copies of the stream, or get all those stats you need (average, max, min) by using a single reduction operation.

For the former method, you need to know what the source of the stream is, i.e. some sort of `Supplier<Stream<Integer>>` that gives you a new stream every time you call `get`, and call it multiple times:

```
// Rather than passing in someList.stream(), you would instead pass in someList::stream, for example
public static double normalizedMean(Supplier<Stream<Integer>> streamSupplier) {
    Integer max = max(streamSupplier.get());
    Integer min = min(streamSupplier.get());
    Integer sum = sum(streamSupplier.get());
    long count = count(streamSupplier.get());
    return (double) ((sum / count) - min) / (max - min);
}
```

As you can probably tell, this is not a very good way of doing things as you needlessly iterate over the stream multiple times.

For the latter method, there is a built in collector called `summarizingInt` that returns a `IntSummaryStatistics` from which you can get all the stats you need.

```
public static double normalizedMean(Stream<Integer> stream) {
    var stats = stream.collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(x -> x));
    int max = stats.getMax();
    int min = stats.getMin();
    double average = stats.getAverage();
    return (average - min) / (max - min);
}
```

I would also suggest you to just take in an `IntStream` instead. This way you avoid the boxing/unboxing and can just do:

```
var stats = stream.summaryStatistics();
```

Comment: Good answer. Upvoted. You can also get an IntSummaryStatistics result using stream.collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(i -> i)).

Answer (score 2):

You should stream into an ordered Collection, and gain information such as the max, min and count in one iteration (first element, last element, size of Collection)
You can then call .stream().sum() again to find the sum.

As such:

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(normalizedStream(Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
    }

    public static double normalizedStream(Stream < Integer > stream) {
        List < Integer > sortedList = stream.sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Integer max = sortedList.get(sortedList.size() - 1);
        Integer min = sortedList.get(0);
        long count = sortedList.size();
        Integer sum = sortedList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        return (double)((sum / count) - min) / (max - min);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think I can call stream again after piping it into an ordered collection

Comment: Call stream on the collection to calculate the sum. Not the original stream.

Answer (score 0):

*the from scratch lambda solution as a blueprint for problems for which there is no prepared build in collector*

```
public static double normalizedMean(Stream<Integer> ints) {
  int[] min = {Integer.MAX_VALUE};
  int[] max = {Integer.MIN_VALUE};
  long[] count = {1};
  return ints.collect(collectingAndThen(reducing((a, b) -> {
    min[0] = min[0] == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? min(a, b) : min(min[0], b);
    max[0] = max[0] == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? max(a, b) : max(max[0], b);
    count[0]++;
    return(a + b);
  }), m -> (((double)m.get()) / count[0] - min[0]) / (max[0] - min[0])));
}
```

if `normalizedMean()` is not `static`:
`min`, `max` and `count` could be defined as scalar class variables
`int min;` `int max;` `long count;`